# fedora 15, oracle 11, python3: can't find or open libclntsh.so.11.1

Tags: fedora, oracle-database

I am trying to use `cx_Oracle` on `Fedora 15` with `Oracle 11`.

I have install `Oracle` and `InstantClient` rpms and also `cx_Oracle` rpm for `CentOS`. I am exporting `ORACLE_HOME` and other like this:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export ORACLE_SID=XE
```

However, `libclntsh.so.11.1` lies here:

/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1

I wonder, if that is not the problem. However Oracle was already installed in this `u01` directory (I don't know what is it, on Ubuntu it installed in the right place). Could you suggest me, what I can do with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the answer! I didn't need to install again InstantClient, as the `libclntsh.so.11.1` was already in the oracle installation. I needed to add another environment variable to `.bashrc`:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib`