# fedora 15, oracle 11: can't login using sqlplus

Tags: fedora, oracle-database

So yesterday I was fighting with [importing cx_Oracle](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14797/fedora-15-oracle-11-python3-cant-find-or-open-libclntsh-so-11-1) and it finally worked. However, I could not connect to the database. So I checked sqlplus to find out, whether I can connect to my Oracle database at all. I have tried both SYS and SYSTEM with the password I set during configuration as well as SCOTT/TIGER, but nothing helps and I get always the same error. This is what is printed:

```
[gruszczy@gruszczy-laptop matches]$ sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Beta on Sat Jun 11 12:33:48 2011

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: sys
Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


Enter user-name: system
Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


Enter user-name: scott
Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

Do you have any idea, what might not have been set? I have found information on Google, that I need to have no trailing slash in ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID set. I have done both those things:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export ORACLE_SID=XE
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
```

Is there anything that I have done wrong or do I have to set up something more?

**EDIT**

My tnsnames.ora:

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = gruszczy-laptop)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

**EDIT**

I tried doing suggested operations and got this:

```
$ sudo su - oracle
$ -bash-4.2$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Beta on Sat Jun 11 21:47:15 2011

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> startup
ORA-00119: invalid specification for system parameter LOCAL_LISTENER
ORA-00130: invalid listener address '(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=gruszczy-laptop)(PORT=1521))'
SQL> Disconnected

-bash-4.2$ lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Beta on 11-JUN-2011 21:47:43

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 2: No such file or directory
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=gruszczy-laptop)(PORT=1521)))
```

This doesn't say me anything and I have no idea, how this all should be configured. I have never had to set this up before. Also usually before I try doing anything I start database with 'Start Database' application.

Comment: BTW, Oracle installation manual contains directions how to set up shared memory correctly. Did you follow them? Also, what's in your tnsnames.ora?

Comment: No, I have not used directions form Oracle installation manual. Previously when I installed Oracle 10 (32bit) on Ubuntu 10.10 I didn't have to do much more beside what I already did. I have edited my question with my tnsnames.ora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your database is not started. Connect with

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Then issue the `startup` command.

Also make sure the listener is up and running with `lsnrctl status` (`lsnrctl start` if it's not running).

Comment: I have tried doing what you recommended and got some output I have no idea how to use. Could you help me a little more?

Comment: This blog is about Oracle 11g on F14 but should work on F15: http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2010/12/installing-oracle-11g-release-2-on-fedora-14.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a trailing `/` at the end of the `ORACLE_HOME` entry in the `listener.ora` configuration file?

If so, remove it.